# Change non-meta design to match Material Design guidelines

Tags: feature-request, design

Google released [Material Design Guidelines](https://www.google.fr/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) and Android Lolipop (5.0) is fully using this guidelines. As the non-meta site still use old icon (from Gingerbread, It's a great occasion to give a **major refresh on Android Enthusiasts Exchange**.

*Any edit with some example of what it could be is appreciate.*

Comment: A similar proposal was made [for Holo](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/getting-rid-of-the-gingerbread-icons) and no action was taken.

Comment: @eldarerathis was for the whole website, not only icon. I hope the request will be assess.